# Should we always catch an Exception, wrap it and pass it on up?

Tags: exception

I've read such a method:

```
public void doSomething throws MyException{
    ...
    try {
         doSomthingElse();
    } catch (MyException e){
         log.errer(e.getMessage());
         throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    ...
}
```

But I prefer to:

```
public void doSomething throws MyException{
     ...
     doSomthingElse();         
     ...
}
```

Anyone knows any reason for the first method? There is only one type of Exception, and it is not handled in this method, is there any reason to catch it, wrap it without new information, and then pass it on up?Why not just write it in the second way? Thanks!

Comment: Why does everyone feel like they need to catch exceptions? Don't catch stuff you can't *do anything with*. The exceptions automatically bubble up the stack if you don't touch them. There's absolutely no reason to *re-throw* them (and doing so has negative consequences, like losing valuable information). And if you *can* do something with the exception, well, you're bordering suspiciously on the territory of using exceptions for flow control, which you probably shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logging exception and throwing it further is actually an anti-pattern for several [reasons](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/05/clean-code-clean-logs-log-exceptions.html). The rule of thumb is: if you can't do anything useful to handle the exception (logging is *not* handling the exception in most cases), let your framework/container do it for you. If you can (for instance use different storage when database is not available, queue packages when network is down), log the exception and proceed (always remember to log stack as well).

If you have a checked exception, wrap it in runtime one and rethrow (create your custom exception or look for existing one that match your needs).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the relationship between the classes. In general I prefer to delegate logging to the caller. Usually is the caller who knows how to handle an exception, too: retry? notify the user? log? forget?

[Misko Hevery is a good read](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/09/16/checked-exceptions-i-love-you-but-you-have-to-go/) on the subject, too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this "wrapper" in your example might be not *ever* miss an exception and at least log it. I see no other sense in that `catch` block, as those are usually declared to recover from an exception and maybe do "proper cleanup".

I prefer inheriting a custom exception class from an existing exception.

In that new exception's constructor, the logging takes place. That way, I'll save the overhead of generating another new Exception with full trace, and the other overhead going with it.

Answer (score 0):

Other than wanting to log the exception or do something else with it "locally", i don't see any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to catch and log the specific error where it occurs as for better logging, but then handle it on a higher level by throwing a new Exception.

Comment: That should not be a reason, since the logging may be done in higher level (the caller of method doSomething), and from the stacktrace we can figure out the location of Exception.

Comment: Yes that is true, but you might not want to log every Exception on a higher level, (for some reason), and if its a generic Exception, recasting to a specfic Exception or add a message might be useful to handle it in a specific way higher up.